# Initial Value Problem uniqueness - Why is the uniqueness theorem not contradicted?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the initial value problem  $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{t^2 + 4x} - t}{2}$, $x(2) = -1$ and know that $x = \frac{-t^2}{4}$ and $x = 1-t$ are solutions to this problem. I want to know why the uniqueness theorem below is not contradicted:

> If $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are continuous in the
>   rectangle $R = \{ (t,x) \mid |t-t_0| \leq \alpha, |x-x_0| \leq \beta \}$
>   , then the initial value problem has a unique solution in the
>   interval $|t-t_0| < \min(\alpha, \frac{\beta}{M})$, where $M$ is the
>   maximum of $|f(t,x)| \in R$.

So $(t_0,x_0) = (2,1)$, and $R = \{(t,x) \mid |t-2| \leq \alpha, \; |x-1|\leq \beta\}$, and $f(t,x) = \frac{\sqrt{t^2 +4x} - t}{2}$.

I'm guessing only one of the solutions is contained within the interval $|t-2| \leq \min(\alpha, \frac{\beta}{M})$, but I'm not sure how to proceed to find this interval. Even then, how do I figure which solution is contained within that interval?

Comment: $x = 1-t$ is only a valid solution when $(t-2) \ge 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $t<2$, if $x = 1-t$, then
$$\frac{\sqrt{t^2+4x}-t}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{t^2-4t+4}-t}{2} = \frac{|t-2|-t}{2} = \frac{(2-t)-t}{2} = 1-t. $$
Since $\frac{dx}{dt} = -1$ if $x = 1-t$, it follows that $x=1-t$ is not a solution to $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt{t^2+4x}-t}{2}$ on any interval containing values $t$ where $t<2$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to Answer my question. If $t < 2$, then the initial condition $x(2) = -1$ cannot be satisifed so couldn't we immediately say that for $t<2$, $x = 1-t$ is not a solution? Otherwise, I agree with what you said.

Comment: @Taln I'm not sure what you mean by "if $t<2$ then the initial condition $x(2)=-1$ cannot be satisfied". It is true that $x=1-t$ is not a solution on intervals strictly to the left of $2$ (and it's true that it can't satisfy the initial condition b/c the initial condition is meaningless in that case), but it's also true that it is not a solution on intervals which contain any parts to the left of $2$, like $(1,3)$ or $(1.9,2.1)$. In particular, it is not a solution on the interval $|t-2|<\delta$ for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: Ah, I got bit confused in my head. Sorry and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not differentiable on the curve $x=-\frac{t^2}4$ and furthermore has an unbounded derivative around that curve. Thus the uniqueness theorem does not apply.

Set $y=4x+t^2$, then
$$
y'(t)=4x'+2t=2\sqrt{y}
$$
is the standard example for the difference between the Peano and Picard-Lindelöf theorems.